# undefined reference when using distcc in CMAKE for Protobuf

Tags: makefile, cmake, protobuf-c, distcc

I am able to cmake protobuf directly, but want to do it via distcc

and all the times, it is throwing error as `undefined reference to`

I added`CXXFLAGS="-static-libstdc++"` to the configure and triggered the cmake. Still getting the same error

Any ideas? 
Let me know if you need more information

Comment: We definitely need **more information**. About your **exact steps** and the **exact error message**.